# Stored procedure is not execute in java

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am using `MS Sql server 2008` and my `sp exec` format is :

```
"K1ERP"."dbo"."Sel_RptProdWiseSaleSumm";
 1 '103', '0', '1151', '20141001', '20141013'
```

It successfully executes in Database server but fails to get data from using `Callable Statement` and `Result Set`. The `1` after `;` could be the problem.

To call I am using

```
CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall
("{call Sel_RptDaywiseProduction('105', '201410', 'DIERP')}");
```

so anybody have any idea how to run this.....please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any stacktrace or exception?

Comment: `Sel_RptDaywiseProduction` and `Sel_RptProdWiseSaleSumm` are two different stored procedures. Which one is having issues?

Comment: but it did't return any value using result set

Comment: please tell what is meaning of  The 1 after ; could be the problem."K1ERP"."dbo"."Sel_RptDaywiseProduction";
 1 '103', '0', '1151', '20141001', '20141013'